# What is the best way to return the uniform response for each API in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, api

I want to know the best way to return the uniform response for each API. For Example:

If success it should respond:

```
{
  statusCode: 200,
  message: "customMessage",
  results: [{...}]
}
```

If failure it should respond (For Example):

```
{
  statusCode: 404,
  message: "customMessage",
  results: []
}
```

Is it a good idea to use `ResponseBodyAdvice` or better to create e.g. `SuccessDTO` or `ErrorDTO` and return directly from each controller method.

I would welcome some examples on `ResponseBodyAdvice`, if this is the best solution.

Comment: Do you really need the `SuccessDTO`? Just use the HTTP status code for that and return the results.

Answer (score 2):

1. Create SuccessDTO and return it for all success scenarios.

   ```
   {

     "data": {
       "name": "Ram",
       "id": "101"
     },
     "message": "user has been added",
     "status": 200,
     "timeStamp": "2021-12-02T14:51:35.733+00:00",
     "path": "/api/v1/user/"

   }
   ```

   Note:- Data field will be having the response data
2. Create ErrorDTO and return for failure/exception cases ( Better to use controller advice).

   ```
   {
       "message":"Not be able to add user"
       "status":400
       "timeStamp":"2021-12-02T14:51:35.733+00:00"
       "path":""/api/v1/user/"
   }
   ```

   Note: In case of Error/Exception there will be no data field.

Similar details are available in the below link.

https://medium.com/codestorm/custom-json-response-with-responseentity-in-spring-boot-b09e87ab1f0a